# Creating a certain hash map from two lists

Tags: list, python-2.7, function, hashmap

I realize you might quickly flag this as a duplicate, but I have looked and can't find anything to help with the *specific* issue I'm having within generating my hashmap between two lists.

I'm dealing with many variables, so I'll simplify it: I have a list of labels `vars = ['L1', 'L2']`. I want to create a second list `values = [rL1, rL2]` in which `rL1` and `rL2` are random (unknown) integers assigned to the labels above, defined by (for example) `rL1 = random.randit(0,10)`.

My goal is to create a hash-map of the form:

`{'L1' : rL1, 'L2' : rL2}`.

Notice the values (integers) should not be contained in quotes.

Right now I have:

```
def genSampVal(vars):
     rL1 = random.randit(0,10)
     rL2 = random.randit(0,20)
     values = ["r" + vars[i] for i in xrange(0, len(vars))]
     print dict(zip(vars, values))
vars = ['L1', 'L2']
genSampVal(vars)
```

But this gives me

`{'L1' : 'rL1', 'L2' : 'rL2'}`.

I've tried playing with `.join` and so forth, but I get back some super strange things.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: To show you what I'd like here's a continuing example. If I create the hash-map myself, I can set

`map = {'L1' : rL1, 'L2' : rL2}`

where printing the map would yield something like

`{'L1' : 8, 'L2' : 13}`.

Since I'm dealing with many, many variables, and I don't want to type my hash-map by hand manually, I'm looking for a function which will handle this for me. The one I've constructed doesn't seem to remember that its values are integers.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean {'L1': random_value, 'L2': random_value}, BTW its random.randint

```
def genSampVal(vars):
    values = [random.randint(0,10) for i in xrange(len(vars))]
    return dict(zip(vars, values))


vars = ['L1', 'L2']
print genSampVal(vars)
```